# Baking - Substitutions for a gingersnap crust

Tags: baking, substitutions, crust

I'm making a recipe that calls for gingersnap crumbs in a crust. I don't really want to make a trip to the store to try and find gingersnaps but I have graham cracker crumbs. Could I just put a bit of ginger or molasses with the graham to make gingersnaps or is there a better way to substitute gingersnap crumbs?

Thanks in advance for all help!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you look for a similar recipe that makes its crust from the crackers you have, then add ginger to that. The fat content (and therefore the fat you need to add) will vary, as will the sugar. I've done almost the opposite substitution on a chocolate cheesecake and could have been a bit more careful to get the texture right.

I'm told Graham crackers are very suitable for a crust, certainly the nearest equivalents over here are, so it it just a matter of getting the substitution right.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, do you really need the ginger?  If not then your problem is solved.  If possible (taste availability you have), why not try an alternative such as cinnamon or other type of spice?